# using gsub in awk to replace a word with parentheses

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression, string

Hi how can I use gsub to replace a word which has parentheses.

Here I want to replace ABC(T) with ABC/G

```
awk ' {gsub("ABC\(T\)","ABC/G")}; Print $0' "$FILENAME" > tmp.tmp && mv tmp.tmp "$FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simplify the whole thing if you use the `//` format for `gsub`:

```
$ echo "ABC(T)" | awk '{gsub(/ABC\(T\)/,"ABC/G")}; print $0'
ABC/G
```

Then, you could simplify further by using `print` with no arguments (which is the same as `print $0`) or the `1` shorthand for printing (the default `awk` action for expressions that evaluate to true, such as `1;` is to print the current line):

```
$ echo "ABC(T)" | awk '{gsub(/ABC\(T\)/,"ABC/G")}1'
ABC/G
```

Personally, however, I wouldn't use `awk` for this, the syntax is shorter and cleaner with other tools:

```
$ echo "ABC(T)" | sed 's|ABC(T)|ABC/G|'
ABC/G

$ echo "ABC(T)" | perl -pe 's|ABC\(T\)|ABC/G|'
ABC/G
```

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. You just needed two `\`. That is because one of set is for the text itself passing through BASH, and the other would be the actual `\` which is being parsed by awk. This seems to work for me:

```
echo 'ABC(T)' | awk ' {gsub("ABC\\(T\\)","ABC/G")}; Print $0' "$FILENAME"
```

And gives:

```
ABC/G
```